# Как установить кодеки в chromium puppeteer'a?

Tags: windows, chromium, puppeteer

Chromium не поддерживает h.264
Как восполнить этот пробел?

Answer (score 1):

вот тут
https://chromium.woolyss.com/
скачал портабл
и содержимое папки bin в "..puppeteer.local-chromium\win64-672088\chrome-win"
thanks https://www.reddit.com/r/Chromium/comments/6awib7/h264_support_in_chromium_windows/